# css spin class on text has a very annoying radius

Tags: css

I have a css spin class I found. It works well on other elements, but when I apply it to text, it has a very annoying radius. how do I get the axle of the spin to be in the middle of the text like it should?

```
.spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what **element** your text is in, but the key is in the **[`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** property. Any [**block-level element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) will be full width by default (such as `<div>`). You can force the element to be inline-block with `display: inline-block`, which will constrain the width of the element to the edge of the text, and cause the rotation to function as expected.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spin">Spin</div>
```

Note that this will **only** work for `inline-block` displays, and **not** `inline` displays, as for rotation to work you need the element to be able to adjust its positioning in the container.